# Algebraic Statistics textbook

Tags: st.statistics, books

Hey
A friend and I are thinking of having an algebraic statistics seminar next semester. Does anyone know of a good book to try learn it out of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard that [the book of Sturmfels and Pachter](http://bio.math.berkeley.edu/ascb/) is supposed to be good.  But it's a bit slanted towards biological applications, which may or may not be what you're into.

Answer (score 8):

I took a course in Algebraic Statistics from the book of Drton, Sturmfels, and Sullivant called "[Lectures on Algebraic Statistics](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/applied+probability+and+statistics/book/978-3-7643-8904-8)". I learned a lot from the book, and I enjoyed the material tremendously.  (My background is in algebraic geometry, by the way.)

Comment: Seth Sullivant has a newer work-in-progress online book here: http://www4.ncsu.edu/~smsulli2/Pubs/asbook.html